# A fast linux distro for django development

Tags: python, linux-distributions

I'm using a old machine - 512mb RAM, 1.9 Ghz, Centrino and I am trying to build a minimalistic environment for python/django development. I only need a decent browser, the terminal and good ol' vim. Can you guys suggest a good linux distro for this purpose.

PS: I tried Linux Mint 9 XFCE but my wireless driver is not working. I hope the distros suggested are not that old to not have necessary hardware support.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

I'd go with [Arch](http://www.archlinux.org/). It's highly tweakable and comes with the bare minimum. I've used it for other low memory setups. I have to warn you that you need to do a lot yourself, but since you are only using it for a limited scope, I don't think you will run into a lot of issues.